# 2.81: Where is the "Preferences option allows using the File Browser in full-screen layout."?

Tags: interface

I cannot seem to find this option.

Where is the "Preferences option allows using the File Browser in full-screen layout."?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello :). Could you please mark one of the answers as accepted **✓**? Just to keep this site nice and tidy :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the Preferences, first tab.

*Preferences->Interface->Temporary windows*

And don't forget to save the preferences :).

[image]